# HTML Structure how do i wrap whole content inside div or section

Tags: html, css, frontend

i am little confused with html structure, should i wrap whole content inside inside div or section, because am making body 90% width apart from footer

```
<body>
    <div class="homepage">
        <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            navigation
        </nav> <!-- Nav End -->
        <header>
            Header content 
        </header> <!-- Header End -->
        <section class="product">
            Main content 
        </section>
        <!-- <hr class="Hhr"> -->
    </div> <!-- Homepage End -->
    <footer>
        Footer copyrights annd social icons
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well you should perhaps rather be using `main` than a `div` ...

Comment: @CBroe is that okay to use header and section inside main ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you style the `.homepage` class only? Like this:

```
<style>
.homepage{
    width:90%;
    /*more styling here...*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, am using that what you mentioned, what i want to make sure is that okay to wrap content whole content inside div ?

Comment: Yap! It&#39;s okay, no harm. @harry

Answer (score 0):

Body should have default witdht and heigth (or 100%)

In the body, you can divide it in sections (big blocks) like header, page-content, footer. (But you can use  and  tags but they are like sections too)

Imagine a newspaper.

```
<body>
  <section class="header"> 
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Subtitle</p>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
      ... Your menu
      <ul>
        <li> ....
          ...
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <section class="content">
    <div class="news">
      <div id="new1">
        .....
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="rrss">
      ....
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="footer">
    ...
    <p> Copyright </p>
  </section>
<body>
```

Then you can give diferent styles to the diferent parts of page.

```
<style>
  body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .header{
    width: 90%;
  }
  ...
  ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the solution that you want, but it is not mandatory to wrap whole content inside the `div` to make it's `width` 90%.

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  width: 90%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

.homepage {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

section {
  background-color: red;
}

footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div style="width: 100%">
    <div class="homepage">
      <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        navigation
      </nav>
      <!-- Nav End -->
      <header>
        Header content
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      </header>
      <!-- Header End -->
      <section class="product">
        Main content
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      </section>
      <!-- <hr class="Hhr"> -->
    </div>
    <!-- Homepage End -->
    <footer>
      Footer copyrights annd social icons
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>
```